# Constructor parameter is null when referred to in an overrided method

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

My code is written in Kotlin. I have a config class defined in a file along 2 more classes as below:

```
@Configuration
class MultipartConfig(private val multipartProperties: MultipartProperties) {
  @Bean
  fun multipartResolver(): StandardServletMultipartResolver {
    val multipartResolver = MultipartResolver(multipartProperties)
    multipartResolver.setResolveLazily(this.multipartProperties.isResolveLazily)
    return multipartResolver
  }
}

class MultipartResolver(private val multipartProperties: MultipartProperties) :
    StandardServletMultipartResolver() {

  override fun resolveMultipart(request: HttpServletRequest): MultipartHttpServletRequest {
    return MultipartHttpServletRequest(multipartProperties, request)
  }
}

class MultipartHttpServletRequest(
    private val multipartProperties: MultipartProperties, request: HttpServletRequest
) : StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest(request, multipartProperties.isResolveLazily) {

  override fun handleParseFailure(ex: Throwable) {
    val msg = ex.message
    if (msg != null && msg.contains("size") && msg.contains("exceed")) {
      throw MaxUploadSizeExceededException(multipartProperties.maxFileSize.toMegabytes(), ex)
    }
    throw MultipartException("Failed to parse multipart servlet request", ex)
  }
}
```

When I debug this code, in the class `MultipartHttpServletRequest`, constructor property `multipartProperties` is NOT null but the same property in the `throw MaxUploadSizeExceededException(multipartProperties.maxFileSize.toMegabytes(), ex)` is ALWAYS null. I cannot understand why this is happening.

Could someone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just answering my own question for clarity. I figured out the issue. It was related to the constructor of that class `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest`. Below is the code of the constrcutor.

```
public StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request, boolean lazyParsing)
    throws MultipartException {

    super(request);
    if (!lazyParsing) {
        parseRequest(request);
    }
}
```

Now, inside of `parseRequest` there is a catch block (for brevity I'm not posting the whole code of the method)

```
catch (Throwable ex) {
  handleParseFailure(ex);
}
```

When the constructor of the super class is throwing exception the child's constructor will not get a chance to initialize.